# NSOpenPanel is not opening when presented as sheet but opens when run modally

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appstore-sandbox, nsopenpanel

I have turned on App sandbox and ticked USB access and User Selected File (read only).

When I try to open NSOpenPanel modally, it opens

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"txt", nil];

[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection: NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openPanel setCanCreateDirectories:NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
[openPanel setDirectoryURL:[self getFileURL]];

 [openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSURL*  selectedFileUrl = [[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

    }

}];
```

This is the code to open as sheet:

```
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[NSApp mainWindow] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSURL*  selectedFileUrl = [[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

}];
```

**Nothing happens when I execute above code.**

> NSURL is : file:///Volumes/SE23/documents/My%.File.txt

Comment: The modal sheet is use of an accessory view (NSView), not a window.  You don't have the right concept to begin with.

Comment: I would suggest that it's the right concept as documented. But NSOpenPanel is voodoo: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478020/presenting-nsopenpanel-as-sheet-synchronously